# how to access alfresco-global.properties from FTL based on environments

Tags: alfresco-share

I have extended the footer page that is deployed as a separate jar in alfresco share[webapps/share/WEB-INF/lin/xx.jar] and try to display the value in ftl file  by reading the value from alfresco-global.properties that is placed in the below path.Is it possible to display the value in ftl file from global properties file?This value should be changed based on environments.

C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes

alfresco-global.properties

---

displayValue=xyz

footer.get.html.ftl

---

```
<@markup id="footer-extension-html" target="html" action="replace" scope="global">
   <@uniqueIdDiv>
      <div class="footer ${fc.getChildValue("css-class")!"footer-com"}">
         <span class="copyright">
            <a href="#" onclick="Alfresco.module.getAboutShareInstance().show(); return false;"><img src="${url.context}/res/components/images/${fc.getChildValue("logo")!"alfresco-share-logo.png"}" alt="${fc.getChildValue("alt-text")!"Alfresco Community"}" border="0"/></a>
            <#if licenseHolder != "" && licenseHolder != "UNKNOWN">
               <span class="licenseHolder">${msg("label.licensedTo")} ${licenseHolder}</span><br>
            </#if>
            <span>${msg(fc.getChildValue("label")!"label.copyright")}</span><br><br>
            <span style='margin-left:175px;'><font size="1">Display Value*******</font>:<b><font face="verdana" color="green">${displayValue}</font></b></span>
         </span>
      </div>
   </@>
</@>
```

footer-extension.xml

---

```
    <extension>
        <modules>
            <module>
                <id>application Footer Extension</id>
                <description>Display Value</description>
                <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
                <customizations>
                    <customization>
  <sourcePackageRoot>com.xxxts.components.footer</sourcePackageRoot>
  <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco.components.footer</targetPackageRoot>
                    </customization>
                </customizations>
            </module>
        </modules>
    </extension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't access the global properties from a FreeMarker template as you are trying to do. The fundamental reason for this is that global properties are configured for the Alfresco Repository, not Share.

If you want to access configurable properties you're better off defining them in the XML configuration files used by Share.

This question is asked and answered in more detail [here](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/accessing-variables-alfresco-globalproperties) on the Alfresco Forums.

Comment: I am able to access property value in ftl by defining properties in spring bean defined in custom-slingshot-application-context.xml and placed in alfresco/web-extension folder.<bean id="webscripts.resources" class="org.alfresco.i18n.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
  <property name="resourceBundles">
   <list>
      <value>alfresco-global</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: So that's fixed the problem? Might be worth upvoting the answer and marking it as the accepted solution :-)

Comment: actually in that forum,he is not clearly given the answer and also its has been chaged a lot since.I am using 4.2 version.you are telling to define in xml but no body is giving clear answer either here nor in the forums.